# Chromecast iOS sender link from youtube

Tags: ios, youtube, chromecast

I want to create an application which takes a youtube URL and plays it on a chromecast from iOS.

I followed the example from google, but my video won't play on the chromecast.

This is the code I use for the GCKMediaInformation:

```
   GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation =
[[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:
 @"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_WNRZ29WNI"
                                    streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeNone
                                   contentType:@"video/mp4"
                                      metadata:metadata
                                streamDuration:0
                                    customData:nil];
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that; the URL that you are sending to chromecast for the media is a YouTube specific URL; you need to send a url that points to a supported media format (see the list of supported media formats [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media))

Comment: are you sure that youtube videos are not supported? can you send me a reference ? i can't find any

Comment: I am sure. It is not common to list all the providers and name which ones are supported or not, instead Chromecast documentation lists the types of supported formats and the URL that you get from YouTube is not pointing to a supported media. The media that is served by YouTube might be of the supported format but the URL that you get from YouTube is not pointing directly to that media.